# Regularity of Boundaries

Tags: general-topology, analysis

From my understanding, regularity of boundaries are effectively talking about the continuity of the boundary of a set. For example, if I consider $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\Omega$ is the unit circle, then $\partial \Omega$ is $C^\infty$ since $\partial \Omega$ describes the functions $x^2+y^2 =1$ which is infinitely differentiable. My understanding of $C^k$ regularity of a bounded set is therefore quite easy to interpret in terms of 2 dimensions and upwards. My question concerns itself with the one dimensional case. What does it mean to be $C^k$ regular for a bounded interval in particular?

Comment: in the one dimensional case the concept does not make sense.

Comment: Then my question moves onto fractional sobolev spaces, I know you need some form of regularity in higher dimensions to have the natural embedding where if $s>s^\prime$, $s,s^\prime$ aren't necessarily integers so that $W^{s,p}(\Omega) \subset W^{s^\prime,p}(\Omega)$. Does that mean in one dimension we can forego regularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not usual to think of the boundary of $(a,b)$ as a manifold; but I guess we could. It is an infinitely smooth $0$-dimensional manifold (albeit a disconnected one).

More to the point of Sobolev embedding. They need smoothness (roughly speaking) so that we can extend a function across the boundary, thus reducing the problem on $\Omega$ to a problem on $\mathbb R^n$. The ideal boundary is flat, a hyperplane. Smooth boundaries are good because they can be mapped to a hyperplane by a smooth change of variables.

In $\mathbb R^1$, a hyperplane is a point. The boundary of $(a,b)$ consists of two hyperplanes. Whatever  extension arguments are used in multidimensional case also work here. The embedding holds.

Comment: Thankyou, that was the exact answer I was looking for.